# How to fix React Native error when first launch

Tags: android, react-native

How to fix this error when run android emulator?

I create a first application using `React Native`. But when I try to run this command `react-native run-android` I got some error in my command line :

[image]

This app is default created app from react native CLI

Comment: Does your `react-native run-android` first try start an emulator ?

Comment: @mfrachet yes.. My first app, no edit code anything

Comment: Instead, can you try to launch your emulator before running your app ? It's maybe an issue due to the fact that the emulator isn't already fully started when RN tries to install the app

Comment: @mfrachet my emulator is still open before I run `react-native run-android` command

Comment: Change the Gradle version in `AppName > android > build.gradle` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'` and then give it a go

Comment: Hi @Eden I will try

Comment: Hi @Eden In what files should I edit as you suggest?

Comment: only the `build.gradle` file under android folder (which comes with react-native init) - **not** the one under android/app/build.gradle

Comment: If you wanna stick with version gradle 3.0.0, you can also try adding ```maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }``` to the same file under `buildscript` without performing the previous version change.